# Nginx Rewrite URL replacement for Apache rewrite

Tags: apache, url, url-rewriting, nginx

How do I convert **nginx** equivalent URL rewrite for the following:

```
RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, with a location:

```
# the ?<u> assigns the capture to $u.  Some older pcres need ?P<u>
location ^/read/(?<u>[0-9]+)/?$ {
  rewrite ^ /read/?u=$u last;
}
```

or with just a rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 last;
```

nginx will append the query string by default (you can disable the behavior by adding another ? at the end of the rewrite target).

Comment: I was able to get the required behaviour with 
rewrite ^/read/([0-9]+)/?$ /read/?u=$1 last;  My next question would be should i use the flag as last or permanent. which one would be better for the SEO

Comment: The permanent flag would send a 301 redirect to the client, telling it to fetch /read/?u=$1 itself.  Using last will perform an internal redirect, and the client's address bar will still show /read/123.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a try:

```
rewrite ^read/([0-9]+)/$ /read/?u=$1 permanent;
```

[IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) - hence direct rewrite option.