# Converting parameter based URL's to pretty URL's

Tags: php, jquery, url-rewriting, nginx, friendly-url

Currently I have url's in this format:

http://www.domain.com/members/username/

This is fine.

However each user may have several 'songs' associated with their account.

The url's for the individual song's look like this:

http://www.domain.com/members/username/song/?songid=2

With the number at the end obviously referring to the ID in the MySQL database.

Using jQuery/javascript, the ID is collected from the URL and the database is then queried and the relevent song/page is rendered.

I would like to change these URL's to the following format instead:

http://www.domain.com/members/username/song/songname/

But I have absolutely no idea how to go about it.  I've been doing quite a bit of reading on the subject but haven't found anything quite relevant to my situation.

To further compound the challenge, song names are not always unique.  For instance if we image the song name 'hello' it is quite possible that another song may exist in the database with the same name, albeit with a different song ID.

Given the limit information you are recieving in this question I am quite content with more generalised answers, describing the approach to take.

General info:

- Apache/Nginx proxy
- Backend: PHP
- jQuery/Javascript front end

Comment: Quick question about the uniqueness. Are the songs unique per user, even if they have the same name as another song in the DB? (i.e. one user cannot have two songs called "hello")

Comment: Although they are not currently set that way, they can be without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how do you store songs in the database but an idea:

use URL rewrite to rewrite members/username/song/songname/ to song.php?user=username&song=songname. There are plenty of tutorials here or perhaps try to use an [URL rewrite-generator tool](http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewriting-tool.php).

In song.php, get these GET values. Do a MySQL query where the songname and the username match. Output the result.

Note: it is OBLIGATORY to make that a user can store only one song with a given name. Also, the storing user's name MUST be stored. Else this is impossible.

Comment: That's a fantastic idea and should work perfectly. Thank you. I can't believe I hadn't thought of it myself! I guess I simply have some reading to do on nginx rewriting.

Comment: song.php will have to be set up to handle situations where there are multiple instances of "songname".  Best bet would be to output a list for the user to click from to then fetch the actual song.

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Apache rewrites](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/), in the main httpd.conf file, or an htaccess file if you don't have access to the main config file should suffice

Comment: Thanks danwellman, this was my initial intention also, however I was under the impression that due using nginx as a proxy, simple apache rewrites would not be functional?

Comment: This question has answers that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825111/nginx-rewrite-url-replacement-for-apache-rewrite

Comment: @gordyr: How are you currently handling the /members/username/ path, is it a physical directory, or are you rewriting?

Comment: Thanks... This link combined with axiomer's answer should get me there. Cheers!

Comment: @leigh, it is through rewriting, though not set up by myself. I'm a front end developer by nature but have found myself in a situation of having to rectify this issue.